# Torque Spec for Tie-Rod end to steering knuckle nut

Tags: tie-rod, torque-specification, lacrosse

2006 Buick Lacrosse CXL
I'm replacing the outer tie rod.  I have been unable to find the torque spec for tightening the castle nut which holds the tie rod end to the steering knuckle.  Does anyone have this spec or know where I can find it?  I used to look in the Haynes manual, but the auto stores no longer keep them in stock.
Thanks

Comment: @SolarMike I have the manuals for our other vehicles, but they don't stock them for most vehicles anymore and I don't have time to wait for it to come in the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

"Tighten the nut to 30 N.m plus 120 degrees (22 lb ft plus 120 degrees). Inspect to ensure that 21/2-41/2 threads are visible above the nylon washer."

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a discrepancy? 30Nm is not 34 ft lbs, it is 22 ft lbs.

Comment: @denver you are correct, it's supposed to be 22 ft lbs. it must be mislabeled in the repair procedure. In a torque spec table it shows 22 ft. lbs + 120 degrees.